# How to pass Struts2 property tag as parameter in java function in the jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am having a problem in passing Struts2 property tag as parameter in java function in the jsp.
I am calling a java function like this from jsp,

```
<s:if test="%{DoSomething()}">
```

`DoSomething()` function is in the Action class, and is being called for each record in the iterator.

The problem is that I want to pass this property `<s:property value="userId"/>` in the function `DoSomething` as java string as follow.

```
<s:if test="%{DoSomething("<s:property value="userId">/)}">
```

Can anyone please guide me that how can I do that. I goggled it but did not find anything.

Comment: Basically I just want to pass "s:property" tag as a parameter in java function like this  <s:if test="%{DoSomething( "<s:property value="userId">/)}">

Comment: Show your `DoSomething` method. What type is your `userId`?

Comment: public boolean DoSomething(string User){      if(User!= null){ return true;}              } //it's a simple function. I even removed all the logic, but still I am getting NULL

Comment: 1. Mention people with `@` (e.g. @IdreesHamayun) in that way they get notification. 2. Edit your post instead posting code in comments. 3. You haven't answered about type of your `userId` property.

Comment: But `DoSomething()` *is not a function*, it's a method of some object in Java terms, it could be an action bean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you cannot used Struts2 tag to another Struts2 tag, you can use expression language,
first use `<s:set name="userId" value="userId" />` then use `${userId}`

Comment: @IdreesHamayun: How *this* worked? This doesn't answer your question at all.

Comment: @AleksandrM I was trying to use struts2 tag '<s:property value="userId">' into another struts2 tag '<s:if test', but as @Pankaj@ said we cannot do that so, first I set the the value using the set tag '<s:set name="userId" value="userId" />' then I retrieved that value in java scriptless <% request.getParameter()%>

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:if test="%{DoSomething(userId)}">
```

Comment: It does not work. I am getting null in the action class when I pass  "userId", but when I write '< s:property value="userId">' in the jsp, it displays the value of UserId perfectly.

Comment: @IdreesHamayun Then you need to provide more information, at worst you'd need `%{DoSomething(#userId)}`, but it also depends on what `DoSomething` is, which you don't state.

Comment: DoSomething is a simple boolean function that returns true or false based on the userId passed.

Comment: and we are calling this function in a loop' " <sb:table rows="${entities}" >". Now the function DoSomething() is being called perfectly for each record in the entities. Problem comes when I try to pass s:property value as a parameter. If I pass a simple java string as a parameter it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you wouldn't need to pass in a parameter like this. You are trying to call a method DoSomething from your action class. You want to pass in a parameter  to this method in your action class. The userId must be existing already in you action class otherwise you couldn't be able to get it through the s:property tag. You can just use this userId variable in your DoSomething method of your action class.