# Call Stuts 2 Action Method with Parameter from Variable in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

There's a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554521/how-to-pass-struts2-property-tag-as-parameter-in-java-function-in-the-jsp) that was never answered properly.

I'm trying to call a Struts 2 Action method from a JSP using `<s:property>` and this method takes a param. The value I'd like to pass is in a variable.

```
     <s:set var="myvar" value="..." />
     Value of variable: <c:out value="${myvar}" /> <!-- This works OK -->

     <!-- Now, need to call a method called getActionCategory(str) which takes this var value --> 
     Method call: <s:property value="%{getActionCategory(myvar)}"/>
```

This doesn't work:

- `myvar` comes in as NULL.
- Also, inserting `value="%{getActionCategory(${myvar})}` into the parentheses doesn't work: *According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute [value] does not accept any expressions*
- This simplified reference with no `get` and a param also brings in a NULL for the param value: `<s:property value="actionCategory(myvar)" />` ([contrary to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170413/calling-function-of-action-class-in-jsp-struts2#comment31899737_21170413))

The only thing that works is using literal constants, like `value="%{getActionCategory('abc')}"`, which I don't want.

Comment: It was answered properly (my answer); OGNL has changed more than once in the intervening eight years. My comment on my answer includes the `#`, which was not always required. Tangentially related--it's rare this kind of work belongs in the view layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

`<s:property value="%{getActionCategory(#myvar)}"/>`